# Java 8 and MySQL compare DATE_ADD to a variable date in a MySQL CASE statement. How to format the variable date correctly?

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to compare dates in a MySQL CASE statement.

This works:

```
CASE
    WHEN (DATE_ADD(dob, INTERVAL 10 YEAR) < NOW()) THEN 'M3'
    WHEN (DATE_ADD(dob, INTERVAL 9 YEAR) < NOW()) THEN 'M2'
    WHEN (DATE_ADD(dob, INTERVAL 8 YEAR) < NOW()) THEN 'M1'
    WHEN (DATE_ADD(dob, INTERVAL 7 YEAR) < NOW()) THEN 'U'
ELSE 'LS'
END AS milestoneBracket
```

However, I want to compare to a variable date instead of NOW().

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = new Date();
DateFormat df1;
try {
    date = df.parse(attDate);
    df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
} catch (ParseException e) {
    System.out.println("Exception :" + e);
    return null;
}
System.out.println(df1.format(date)); //displays 2022-07-17
```

Which I place in the CASE statement:

```
WHEN (DATE_ADD(dob, INTERVAL 10 YEAR) < df1.format(date)) THEN 'M3'
```

However, this always defaults to 'LS'.

I have tried:

```
WHEN (DATE_ADD(dob, INTERVAL 10 YEAR) < 'df1.format(date)') THEN 'M3'
```

However, this always returns "M3".

And:

```
WHEN (DATE_ADD(dob, INTERVAL 10 YEAR) < 'df1.format(date)->format('Y-m-d')') THEN 'M3'
```

Which returns an error.

How do I correctly format the variable date to work in the MySQL CASE statement please?

Comment: MySQL can't parse a piece of java code. But if you use `WHEN (DATE_ADD(dob, INTERVAL 10 YEAR) < ?` passing the `date` (the `Date` type) as a prepared statement does that work?

Comment: Stop using `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. They are troublesome and long outdated. Use `LocalDate` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API.